# Take the Output of curl and send to second curl command

Tags: shell, variables, curl, grep

```
curl -s http://meet97263421.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=common-info | \
grep -oP '(?<=<cookie>).*?(?=</cookie>)|(?<=account-id=").*?(?=")' 2>&1\
```

The above curl/grep command returns the following data:

```
na3breezswp8yf3s5fghdgn4
1013353222
```

How do I send these two outputs to a second curl command:

```
curl "https://meet97263421.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?\
action=login&login=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&account-id=[$1]&session=[$0]"
```

I'm using `[$1]` and `[$0]` as place holders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this help:

```
#!/bin/bash

OUT=$(curl -s http://meet97263421.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=common-info \
| grep -oP '(?<=<cookie>).*?(?=</cookie>)|(?<=account-id=").*?(?=")')

# echo $OUT && echo 

Session=$(cut -f1 -d' ' <<< $OUT)
AccountID=$(cut -f2 -d' ' <<< $OUT)

curl "https://meet97263421.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=login&login=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&account-id=$AccountID&session=$Session"

# or 

curl "https://meet97263421.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=login&login=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&account-id=`cut -f2 -d' ' <<< $OUT`&session=`cut -f1 -d' ' <<< $OUT`"
```